# Send email when cell value is set to "Yes"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have combed through tons of answered questions and I'm still not able to make this work. What I want to do is pretty simple, but I don't ever write code, so I'm stuck.

I want an email to be sent out whenever someone sets a cell value to "Yes" from a data validation dropdown in column D.

This is the code I currently have

```
function onEdit(e) {
sendEmails(e)
}

function sendEmails(e){
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var subject = "This is the subject of the email";
  var body = "This is the body of the email";
  var to = "email1@gmail.com";
  var cc = "email2@gmail.com";
  
  if (col == 4 && row > 2 && e.range.getValue() == "Yes"){
    GmailApp.sendEmail({to:to, subject:subject, body:body, cc:cc});
    }
   }
```

I was able to send an email when I used GmailApp.sendEmail() with an onEdit() trigger, so I don't think it's a permissions issue. Something seems like it's breaking in the logic I set up. Like I said, I never code. So I'm lost. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So how is it named? `Gmail.App` or `GmailApp`? If you manage to use `Gmail.App.sendEmail`, than in your example you are missing dot between Gmail and App

Comment: That's a mistake on my part. Just updated that. It's named GmailApp.sendEmail (which is what I used originally when I had success sending the email)

Comment: Do you reach `sendEmails`? What values are in `col`, `row` and `e.range.getValue()`?

Comment: @Justinas I promise I'm not trying to sound like an idiot here, but I'm not quite sure what you mean. Also I'm very appreciative of your time and help with this!

Comment: Try changing to a Installable trigger.  Simple triggers cannot perform functions that require permission like sending emails

Comment: Do not name it onEdit otherwise you will receive two trigger the simple one and installable one.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

Create installable trigger named onMyEdit

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.value == "Yes") {
    var subject = "This is the subject of the email";
    var body = "This is the body of the email";
    var to = "email1@gmail.com";
    var cc = "email2@gmail.com";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, { cc: cc });
  }
}
```

You cannot run these functions without supplying the event object. If you attempt to run from the script editor without supplying the event object you will get an error.  The onEdit trigger is a simple trigger meaning that it cannot perform functions that require permission.  If you need to perform commands that require permission you must create an installable trigger either programmatically or through the editors trigger panel.

There are several limitations running scripts this way.  You will have difficulty using alert and prompt boxes.  They are fairly difficult to debug because the onEdit is not easily run in debug mode so you are left having to edit the appropriate elements on the desired sheet."

- [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Comment: Okay so I dropped that in and updated all the fields. Added an installed trigger to run when there's an edit. And still nothing unfortunately

Comment: Sorry I assumed you had the rest of the code correct but you did not so I corrected it and it now works